# How do I properly match unicode characters with awk's regex?

Tags: regex, shell, unicode, awk

I have the following statement in a script, to retrieve the domain portion of an email address from a variety of email logs with a reliably formatted To: line:

`awk '/^To: / { r = gensub(/^To: .+@(.+) .*$/, "\\1", "g"); print r}'`

This matches lines such as `To: doc@bequerelint.net (Omer)`. However, it does not match the lines `To: andy.vitrella@uol.com.br (André)` or `To: boggers@operamail.com (Pål)`, nor any other line with a non-ascii character within the trailing parentheses after the email address.

Incidentally, `od -c` for the first non-matching example gives:

```
0000000   T   o   :       a   n   d   y   .   v   i   t   r   e   l   l
0000020   a   @   u   o   l   .   c   o   m   .   b   r       (   A   n
0000040   d   r 351   )  \n
0000045
```

I surmise there is something going on with awk's regex's `.` not matching the non-ascii character in `(André)`. What is the correct regex statement to match such a line?

Answer (score 2):

I give my comment as an answer to have the code formatted correctly,

```
$ echo 'To: andy.vitrella@uol.com.br (André)
To: boggers@operamail.com (Pål)' | gawk '/^To: / { r = gensub(/^To: .+@(.+) .*$/, "\\1", "g"); print r}'
uol.com.br
operamail.com
$ echo 'To: andy.vitrella@uol.com.br (André)
To: boggers@operamail.com (Pål)' > fileee12
$ gawk '/^To: / { r = gensub(/^To: .+@(.+) .*$/, "\\1", "g"); print r}' fileee12
uol.com.br
operamail.com
$ env | grep -e '\(LOC\)\|\(LAN\)'
LANG=C
XTERM_LOCALE=C
$
```

as you see, your command works both reading from stdin and reading from a file, using a C locale, so I can exclude that *on my computer* it is the locale or the differences between reading from stdin rather than from a file to make a difference.

My computer has linux, my gawk is 4.1.1, what are your circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

further simplifying it, where locale setting simply doesn't matter

```
 {mawk/mawk2/gawk [-b]? -e} 'BEGIN { FS = "\100";  # ampersand 
      
     } /^To: / && ( NF > 1 ) {                       # play it safe in case 
                                                     # of no ampersand

         print ($2 !~ / /) ? $2 : \                  # in case no "(Omer)" towards the end
               \                                      
               substr($2, 1, index($2, " ") - 1); 
     }'
```

since spaces aren't valid in email address (unless URI-encoded (?)), and you're force delimiting by @ , this substr alone does it without all the gsub and unicode and what not